# Trying to go through all XLSX files within a folder, unprotect them, change value, and protect them

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

From MS Access, I am attempting to open every XLSX file within a folder and edit a specific cell within the excel document. However some of these files are protected and some are not. Therefore I am trying to add an IF statement to check for this potential roadblock (I know the password for the protected workbooks and it is consistent across all of them).

I have tried the below code but it keeps returning various errors after every time I alter some of it to work (current error is "Wrong Number of arguments or invalid property):

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

    Dim xl          As Excel.Application
    Dim wb          As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws          As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim fso         As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder   As Folder
    Dim objFile     As File
    Dim strPath     As String
    Dim strFile     As String
    Dim errnum      As Long
    Dim errtxt      As String

    'Specify the path to the folder.
    strPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\originals"

    '***** Set a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" by using
    '***** Tools > References in the Visual Basic Editor (Alt+F11)

    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject.
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    'Alternatively, without the reference mentioned above:
    'Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Get the folder.
    Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(strPath)

    'If the folder does not contain files, exit the sub.
    If objFolder.Files.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found in the specified folder.", vbApplicationModal + _
        vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Runtime Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Turn off screen updating. It may run quicker if updating is disabled, but
    'if the work to be done is minimal, it may not be necessary.
    Set xl = Excel.Application
    xl.ScreenUpdating = False
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    'Loop through each file in the folder
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        strFile = objFile.Path

        'Open each file and perform actions on it.
        Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)

        'Set inline error trap in case PLOG tab does not exist.
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Whole Foods Market PLOG")
        wb.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        errnum = Err.Number
        errtxt = Err.Description
        On Error GoTo -1

        Select Case errnum
            Case 0 'Zero = no error.
                If ws.ProtectContents = True Then
                        ws.Unprotect "550" 'enter password
                End If
                ws.Cells(11, 20).Value = Date
                ws.Protect "550", True, True
                wb.Save
            Case 9 'Subscript out of range; most likely the tab does not exist.
                MsgBox "The workbook '" & objFile.Name & "' does not have a 'PLOG' tab."
            Case 58
                MsgBox "Fix This"
            Case 91
                Resume Next
            Case Else 'All other errors.
                MsgBox "Runtime error #" & CStr(errnum) & ": " & IIf(Right(errtxt, 1) = ".", errtxt, errtxt & ".")
        End Select

        wb.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        wb.Close False
        Set wb = Nothing

    Next objFile

    'Turn screen updating back on
    xl.ScreenUpdating = True

    'IMPORTANT: Clean up & quit Excel. If this is not done, Excel will stay in memory
    'after the macro ends. If this is done repeatedly, many individual instances of Excel
    'will build up in memory, and will stay there until killed with an task app such as
    'Windows Task Manager or SysInternals ProcessExplorer, or until the system is rebooted,
    'and it may even prevent Windows from shutting down properly because all those instances
    'of Excel are waiting for user input at the "Save workbook? Yes/No/Cancel" dialog.
    xl.Quit
    Set xl = Nothing

End Sub
```

I simply want the code to go through each excel file within the folder and do this:

- if the workbook is protected then

  1. unprotect it,
  2. edit cell,
  3. reprotect it,
  4. save/close
- if the workbook is not protected then

  1. edit cell,
  2. reprotect it,
  3. save/close

Edit1: fixed a typo I saw in the original code

Comment: Which lines have the errors? In addition to the error text, what are the error numbers?

Comment: @spinjector the message sounds vaguely like error 5. Hard to tell where that's happening at a glance though.

Comment: @MAthieu All of the errors seem to be happening after "While fileName <> "".

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> ws.Unprotect "550", True, True
> ```

This would be the "wrong number of arguments". `Worksheet.Unprotect` takes a single, optional, `Password` parameter - VBA doesn't know what to do with these two `True` arguments.

Comment: I remove the True arguments in there and it "progresses" further. Now I receive a "sorry we couldnt find . is it possible it was moved" error  at 'set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open (fileName)'

Comment: Looks like the code you posted isn't the code you're running. Verify the value of `filename`.

Comment: @GregWilliams the code you posted is opening one workbook and closing it several times over, which definitely would be causing problems. `Set wb` and `Set ws` would have to be inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub SO56995486()

    'Declare the variables
    Dim xl          As Excel.Application
    Dim wb          As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws          As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim fso         As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder   As Scripting.Folder
    Dim objFile     As Scripting.file
    Dim fileList    As VBA.Collection
    Dim fldrPath    As String
    Dim fullpath    As String
    Dim filename    As String
    Dim errnum      As Long
    Dim c           As Long
    Dim i           As Long

    'Specify the path to the folder.
    fldrPath = "C:\Temp\"

    'Set up a log file.
    Open fldrPath & "_logfile.txt" For Output As #1

    '***** Set a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" by using
    '***** Tools > References in the Visual Basic Editor (Alt+F11)

    'Set up the major object variables.
    Set xl = Excel.Application
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fileList = New VBA.Collection

    'Get the folder.
    Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(fldrPath)

    'If the folder does not contain files, exit the sub.
    If objFolder.Files.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found in the specified folder.", vbApplicationModal + _
        vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, "Runtime Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Create a list of all XLSX files in the folder.
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        filename = objFile.Name
        If UCase(fso.GetExtensionName(filename)) = "XLSX" Then
            fileList.Add objFile
        End If
    Next

    'Remove any Excel temp files. Tricky loop since items may be deleted.
    i = 1
    Do
        Set objFile = fileList.ITEM(i)
        filename = Left(objFile.Name, 2)
        If filename = "~$" Then
            fileList.Remove (i)
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop Until i >= fileList.Count

    'Remove any open files. Tricky loop again.
    i = 1
    Do
        Set objFile = fileList.ITEM(i)
        fullpath = objFile.Path
        If IsFileOpen(fullpath) Then
            fileList.Remove (i)
        Else
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop Until i >= fileList.Count

    'Turn off screen updating. It may run quicker if updating is disabled, but
    'if the work to be done is minimal, it may not be necessary.
    xl.ScreenUpdating = False
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    'Loop through each file in the folder
    For Each objFile In fileList
        fullpath = objFile.Path
        'Open the file. Use inline error trap in case it can't be opened.
        On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fullpath)
        errnum = Err.Number
        On Error GoTo 0
        Select Case errnum
            Case 0 'File opened ok.
                'Use inline error trap in case PLOG tab does not exist.
                On Error Resume Next
                Set ws = wb.Worksheets("PLOG")
                errnum = Err.Number
                On Error GoTo 0
                Select Case errnum
                    Case 0 'Tab reference grabbed ok.
                        If ws.ProtectContents = True Then
                                ws.Unprotect "550" 'enter password
                        End If
                        ws.Cells(11, 20).value = Date
                        ws.Protect "550", True, True
                        On Error Resume Next
                        wb.Save
                        errnum = Err.Number
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        Select Case errnum
                            Case 0 'Saved ok.
                                Print #1, "OK: " & objFile.Name
                            Case Else
                                Print #1, "Couldn't save: " & objFile.Name
                        End Select
                    Case 9 'Subscript out of range; probably tab does not exist.
                        Print #1, "Tab does not exist: " & objFile.Name
                    Case Else 'Other errors.
                        Print #1, "Other error (" & CStr(errnum) & "): " & objFile.Name
                End Select
            Case Else
                Print #1, "Can't open file: "; Tab(20); objFile.Name
        End Select
        wb.Close True
        Set wb = Nothing
    Next

    'Turn screen updating back on
    xl.ScreenUpdating = True
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True


    'IMPORTANT: Clean up & quit Excel. If this is not done, Excel will stay in memory
    'after the macro ends. If this is done repeatedly, many individual instances of Excel
    'will build up in memory, and will stay there until killed with an task app such as
    'Windows Task Manager or SysInternals ProcessExplorer, or until the system is rebooted,
    'and it may even prevent Windows from shutting down properly because all those instances
    'of Excel are waiting for user input at the "Save workbook? Yes/No/Cancel" dialog.
    xl.Quit
    Set xl = Nothing
    Close #1

End Sub

Public Function IsFileOpen(filename As String) As Boolean

    Dim filenum As Integer
    Dim errnum As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    filenum = FreeFile()
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open filename For Input Lock Read As #filenum
    Close filenum
    errnum = Err
    On Error GoTo 0

    Select Case errnum
        Case 0
            'No error.
            IsFileOpen = False
        Case 55, 70
            'File already open.
            IsFileOpen = True
        Case Else
            'Other error.
            'IsFileOpen = ?
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: I just made a couple quick edits in the past 3 mins.

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it and get "Run-time error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set" on xl.ScreenUpdating - False

Comment: forgot to put your name in the comment above, sorry

Comment: Oh dagnabbit, my apologies, I missed a line of code. I've just edited to add Set xl = Excel.Application, and also some notes regarding the path and proper closing of the XL instance at the end. And then re-tested in my Access to make sure it works. See above.

Comment: i really appreciate your help on this. I put the code into access and run it. It starts and then prompts me with a message saying "file already exists in folder. do you want to overwrite?" I then click "yes" and it starts running again but then popups "excel cannot open file: ~$PLOG - (rest of the file name"

Comment: here is an example of the filename: PLOG - (Acme+) Simmons - 2019.07.10 - (GRO) Wet Pet Food - Units.xlsx

Comment: Ok I think I got it this time. I edited my answer with the new code. Slight change with objFile.Path instead of .Name. I set up a couple test XLS files with sheet names like you're using. It successfully added the date in cell T11. Previously I just had a MsgBox with the filenames and I didn't notice it was only the name and not full path.

Comment: should `set ws =wb.Sheets("Sheet1")` be `set ws =wb.Sheets("PLOG")`. When I leave it as Sheet1 I get a "subscript out of range" error. when i change it to "PLOG" I get a "excel cannot open file: ~$PLOG - (rest of the file name)" error

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure I understand. In your original code it says the PLOG sheet is named `"Whole Foods Market PLOG"`. At the top it says `Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")`, and in the loop it says `Sheet1.Cells(11, 20).Value = Date`. I assumed the latter should have used `ws.`, so for consistency I changed it. You're working with two sheets, `Sheet1` and `PLOG`. Perhaps the code should be modified to have two vars like ws1 and ws2. But `PLOG` is only used in the expression of `If-Then`, so it didn't seem necessary.

Comment: I really appreciate all your help on this for me! all excel workbooks have a sheet named "PLOG" in them. Sorry for the confusion and inconsistency (thats probably why i was having problems with the code originally :-/

Comment: No problem. Doing somehing new and working it out is how one learns. =-) Ok so is the Date supposed to be inserted on 'Sheet1', or on 'PLOG'..? Please clarify what (if any) activity is supposed to happen on either `Sheet1` and `PLOG`. Now I'm wondering if nothing is supposed to happen on `Sheet1`, and it's all on `PLOG`.

Comment: You are correct everything is happening the sheet named "PLOG"

Comment: Ok starting to make sense. I updated my code above; the only change made is `Set ws = wb.Worksheets("PLOG")` and `If ws.ProtectContents = True Then`. So now we are only working on the worksheet `PLOG`, and not jumping back & forth between `PLOG` and `Sheet1`.

Comment: ok i feel like we're really close and I think there is some setting I am missing in my version of MS Access. When I run the script is goes through the folder and then prompts me with "a file named 'PLOG - (Acme) filename" already exists in this location. Do you want to replace it?"......... I then select yes......... then it gives a run-time error 1004 "Excel cannot open the file '~$PLOG - (Acme) filename' (the same filename) because the file format is not valid."

Comment: this occurs on the `set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)` line

Comment: Ok, another update (twice actually). That `Error 1004` is weird. The only change I made that I think might affect it is added `Set wb = Nothing`. I thought perhaps letting the assignment go before trying the next leg of the loop might help. Perhaps checking Windows Task Manager for hidden instances of Excel and killing them might help..? Maybe one is stuck with that file open. Or perhaps even reboot. Access might have something stuck as well. Note: I also beefed up the loop a bit with some error-checking code that traps for a workbook that's missing the `PLOG` tab.

Comment: The version of the code above I pasted just now, I ran through completely here on the collection of test files I built, and I didn't get any errors.

Comment: so the code worked, thank you!!! however it still gives that run-time error 1004 "Excel cannot open the file '~$PLOG - (Acme) filename' (the same filename) because the file format is not valid." I close every instance of excel and restarted the computer; could i just put `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` in there?

Comment: Awesome. What happens if you try to open that same file without the macro running..?

Comment: no issues at all, which makes the error even stranger. should I just put the `DoCmd` in there? Will that prevent any of your code from running correctly?

Comment: Ahhhh..!! I figured it out..!! Those are Excel temp files. Give me a little bit to rearrange the code to filter those out.

Comment: Ok I think I see what's happening. The loop through the folder with fso is "dumb" aka not very aware. If files are added or removed, it just keeps going. When Excel has a file open, it creates a temp file in the same folder, with the prefix "~$". If Excel doesn't close it & delete the temp file fast enough, `objFolder.Files` might pick it up. I tried a few ways to deal with this, and also if a file is already open, but it got complicated. I think `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` is the easiest way to handle it. But also `wb.Close False` so it won't try to save and hang up there. I'll add it above.

Comment: its still not suppressing the messages. I even tried adding a `Case 1004` to your code above and it still raises the prompt. Do you think its how I cam calling the `Public Sub`? I placed all of your code into a module and then assigned a `Function` to a button in my form to run the code. Is there another/better way to do it?

Comment: i figure it out. basically i added another handler for error code 91 and to suppress other messages with the `wb.Application.DisplayAlerts` flag. I've posted the final code above in my OP

Comment: Oh, I just updated my code with extra stuff, lol. Basically it compiles a list of XLSX files in the folder, then removes temp files. Then it removes open files with an extra function IsOpenFile(). Then it takes the list left over and works with that. Also added some more error checking.

Comment: Also, in addition to my most recent comment above, I forgot to mention I also added a logfile to my code. It drops _logfile.txt into the folder, which tells you which files were processed, and if not, what the error was.